# SWI prolog in terminal acting different to SWI software download. OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, prolog, swi-prolog

i am trying to run a simple prolog script that takes a users input and prints it back to the terminal.

```
go :- write('Enter Your Name: '),
        read(Yourname), 
        write('Hello '), write(Yourname), nl.
```

when i load the script in the terminal using `['file.pl']` and then run it, on run it creates a new line but does not print the `Enter Your Name:`. if i press enter it starts a new line beginning with `|:`. if i write `word.` at any point it prints `Enter Your Name: Hello word`.
if i just enter a `.` it prints `Enter Your Name:` followed by `ERROR: Stream user_input:36:18 Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause`.

however if i run the script in the software downloaded from the swi-prolog site it works perfectly fine.

is this a case of not loading the file correctly in the terminal?

Comment: If in the first case you are running SWI Prolog that came with your OSX installation, it's probably a very old version.It's loading the file correctly. It looks to me like it's an output buffering issue.  That is, the first `write` doesn't flush the output before it prompts for the input. Thus it comes out late. What version of SWI Prolog are you running? If you download from the SWI Prolog site you're getting a newer version.

Comment: it appears that where was an update. i was using 7.6.4 checked for an update, and updated to 7.6.4_1